# Медленное умножение матриц 1024х1024

Tags: оптимизация, матрицы, кэширование, производительность, любой-язык

Почему матрицы размеров 1025x1025, 1023x1023 перемножаются быстрее матриц 1024x1024 стандартным алгоритмом?

Comment: потому что это не так

Comment: 1023x1023 разве не должна по определению перемножаться быстрее?

Comment: @Igor да, ето так

Comment: @michael_best интуитивно - да

Comment: так в чем вопрос? или как вы считали время?

Comment: @tesla Нет, это не так. *(Я в восторге от нашей дискуссии!)*

Comment: И что такое "стандартный алгоритм" и главное, как именно этот алгоритм закодирован. Вы же понимаете, что даже перестановка пары ассемблерных инструкций, не влияющих на общую логику может кардинально сказываться на производительности

Comment: @Mike с_ij += a_ik * b_kj для всех i,j,k

Comment: @Mike нет, не понимает

Comment: @tesla Это общая формула. как она реализована в том языке, в котором вы заметили разницу. к массивам можно по разному обращаться, что так же повлияет на скорость из за особенностей кеширования. И почему "любой-язык" на основании чего вы утверждаете, что в любом языке будет тот эффект, который вы описываете ?

Comment: @Mike потому что это верно для большинства мне известных языков, а меток только <= 5. Это может быть неверно для определённых архитектур или экзотических устройств кэша. Реализовано так: три цикла - первый по i, второй по j, третий по k. То есть "в лоб" безо всяких оптимизаций, поэтому я назвал алгоритм стандартным

Comment: Поставил минус вопросу: да, он интересный и заслуживает много плюсов. НО не то, как именно он задан. В вопросе стоило бы сразу показать то, что написал Harry, с таймингами. Вопрос не должен выглядеть как набор голословных утверждений, без доказательств

Comment: @Igor посмотрите на мое решение, оно правильное?

Comment: Вопрос бессмыслен до ужаса. У алгоортма нет понятия времены выполнения и никакого "быстрее" тут быть не может. "Быстрее" или "медленнее" может быть только конкретная реализация алгоритма. А что вы там накосячили в своей конкретной реализации - нам отсюда не видно.

Comment: Я просто тут оставлю, может это объяснит что-то: https://www.researchgate.net/publication/266619255_Accelerated_Multiple_Precision_Matrix_Multiplication_using_Strassen's_Algorithm_and_Winograd's_Variant

Comment: Тут что-то с кратностью размера  строки матрицы с размером кэш линии -- 64 байта. Обмен между уровнями кэша (L1 - 32Kbyte, L2, L3 зависит от модели, а все 3 матрицы 24Mbyte) происходит порциями размером в кэш-линию. А вот что именно сбивает предсказатель предвыборки данных кэшей и в результате функциональные устройства умножения с FP простаивают,  как-то не соображу.

Comment: @avp вы правы, вот аналогичный [вопрос на enSO](https://stackoverflow.com/q/6060985/6944845)

Comment: tesla, у меня возникла подобная проблема, вот здесь описал: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1203896/memcpy-%d0%bd%d0%b5%d0%bc%d0%bd%d0%be%d0%b3%d0%be-%d0%bd%d0%b5%d0%bf%d0%be%d0%bd%d1%8f%d1%82%d0%bd%d0%be-%d1%80%d0%b0%d0%b1%d0%be%d1%82%d0%b0%d0%b5%d1%82

Answer (score 9):

В комментарий не влезет, но это не ответ. Это именно комментарий.

Написал для проверки (см. ниже). Обалдел, ибо у меня, скомпилированное VC++ 2017, таки дало:

```
1023: 2106433
1024: 7664347
1025: 2106884
```

При отключенной оптимизации эффект выражен меньше:

```
1023: 9592402
1024: 11608342
1025: 9480406
```

Это для 64-разрядного приложения. 32-разрядное, впрочем, почти такое же.

```
1023: 2910957
1024: 7729545
1025: 2192236
```

*"А я что? сама в шоке!" (с) Анекдот про пограничную собаку...*

Вот код.

```
#include <vector>
#include <string>
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>
#include <chrono>

using namespace std;

class muTimer
{
    using Clock = std::chrono::high_resolution_clock;
    bool active = false;
    Clock::duration   duration_;
    Clock::time_point start_ = Clock::now(), stop_ = Clock::now();

    muTimer(const muTimer&)             = delete;
    muTimer& operator=(const muTimer&)  = delete;
public:
    using ns       = std::chrono::nanoseconds;
    using mks      = std::chrono::microseconds;
    using ms       = std::chrono::milliseconds;
    muTimer() { reset(); start(); }
    ~muTimer() = default;
    muTimer& reset()
    {
        duration_ = std::chrono::nanoseconds(0);
        active    = false;
        return *this;
    }
    muTimer& start()
    {
        if (!active)
        {
            start_ = Clock::now();
            active = true;
        }
        return *this;
    }
    muTimer& stop()
    {
        if (active)
        {
            stop_      = Clock::now();
            duration_ += stop_ - start_;
            active     = false;
        }
        return *this;
    }
    template<typename T = mks>
        unsigned long long duration()
    {
        return static_cast<unsigned long long>
            (std::chrono::duration_cast<T>(stop_-start_).count());
    }
};


double m1024_1[1024][1024], m1024_2[1024][1024], m1024_3[1024][1024];
double m1025_1[1025][1025], m1025_2[1025][1025], m1025_3[1025][1025];
double m1023_1[1023][1023], m1023_2[1023][1023], m1023_3[1023][1023];

int main(int argc, const char * argv[])
{
    for(int i = 0; i < 1024; ++i)
        for(int j = 0; j < 1024; ++j)
        {
            m1024_1[i][j] = rand();
            m1024_2[i][j] = rand();
        }
    for(int i = 0; i < 1025; ++i)
        for(int j = 0; j < 1025; ++j)
        {
            m1025_1[i][j] = rand();
            m1025_2[i][j] = rand();
        }
    for(int i = 0; i < 1023; ++i)
        for(int j = 0; j < 1023; ++j)
        {
            m1023_1[i][j] = rand();
            m1023_2[i][j] = rand();
        }

    {
        muTimer mt;
        for(int i = 0; i < 1023; ++i)
            for(int j = 0; j < 1023; ++j)
            {
                double s = 0.0;
                for(int k = 0; k < 1023; ++k)
                {
                    s += m1023_1[i][k]*m1023_2[k][j];
                }
                m1023_3[i][j] = s;
            }
        mt.stop();
        cout << "1023: " << mt.duration() << endl;
    }
    {
        muTimer mt;
        for(int i = 0; i < 1024; ++i)
            for(int j = 0; j < 1024; ++j)
            {
                double s = 0.0;
                for(int k = 0; k < 1024; ++k)
                {
                    s += m1024_1[i][k]*m1024_2[k][j];
                }
                m1024_3[i][j] = s;
            }
        mt.stop();
        cout << "1024: " << mt.duration() << endl;
    }
    {
        muTimer mt;
        for(int i = 0; i < 1025; ++i)
            for(int j = 0; j < 1025; ++j)
            {
                double s = 0.0;
                for(int k = 0; k < 1025; ++k)
                {
                    s += m1025_1[i][k]*m1025_2[k][j];
                }
                m1025_3[i][j] = s;
            }
        mt.stop();
        cout << "1025: " << mt.duration() << endl;
    }

}
```

При 1024 ассемблерный код отличается:

Вот основной код для 1024:

```
; 104  :                 for(int k = 0; k < 1024; ++k)
; 105  :                 {
; 106  :                     s += m1024_1[i][k]*m1024_2[k][j];

    movsd   xmm1, QWORD PTR [rcx-8192]
    mulsd   xmm1, QWORD PTR [rax-8]
    movsd   xmm0, QWORD PTR [rax]
    mulsd   xmm0, QWORD PTR [rcx]
    addsd   xmm1, xmm2
    movaps  xmm2, xmm1
    movsd   xmm1, QWORD PTR [rcx+8192]
    mulsd   xmm1, QWORD PTR [rax+8]
    addsd   xmm2, xmm0
    movsd   xmm0, QWORD PTR [rcx+16384]
    mulsd   xmm0, QWORD PTR [rax+16]
    addsd   xmm2, xmm1
    movsd   xmm1, QWORD PTR [rcx+24576]
    mulsd   xmm1, QWORD PTR [rax+24]
    addsd   xmm2, xmm0
    movsd   xmm0, QWORD PTR [rcx+32768]
    mulsd   xmm0, QWORD PTR [rax+32]
    addsd   xmm2, xmm1
    movsd   xmm1, QWORD PTR [rcx+40960]
    mulsd   xmm1, QWORD PTR [rax+40]
    addsd   xmm2, xmm0
    movsd   xmm0, QWORD PTR [rcx+49152]
    mulsd   xmm0, QWORD PTR [rax+48]
    add rcx, 65536              ; 00010000H
    add rax, 64                 ; 00000040H
    addsd   xmm2, xmm1
    addsd   xmm2, xmm0
    sub r8, 1
    jne $LL37@main
```

А вот - для 1023:

```
; 89   :                 for(int k = 0; k < 1023; ++k)
; 90   :                 {
; 91   :                     s += m1023_1[i][k]*m1023_2[k][j];

    movsd   xmm1, QWORD PTR [rcx-8184]
    mulsd   xmm1, QWORD PTR [rax-8]
    movsd   xmm0, QWORD PTR [rcx]
    mulsd   xmm0, QWORD PTR [rax]
    addsd   xmm1, xmm2
    movaps  xmm2, xmm1
    movsd   xmm1, QWORD PTR [rcx+8184]
    mulsd   xmm1, QWORD PTR [rax+8]
    addsd   xmm2, xmm0
    add rax, 24
    add rcx, 24552              ; 00005fe8H
    addsd   xmm2, xmm1
    sub rdx, 1
    jne SHORT $LL28@main
```

Объяснений не даю, сам хочу услышать :)

P.S. Вносим единственное изменение:

```
double m1024_1[1025][1025], m1024_2[1025][1025], m1024_3[1025][1025];
double m1025_1[1025][1025], m1025_2[1025][1025], m1025_3[1025][1025];
double m1023_1[1025][1025], m1023_2[1025][1025], m1023_3[1025][1025];
```

Имеем:

```
1023: 1973593
1024: 1983533
1025: 1981114
```

Comment: Комментарии не предназначены для расширенной дискуссии; разговор [перемещён в чат](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/87628/discussion-on-answer-by-harry----10241024).

Answer (score 1):

Решил и свою лепту внести на `java`.

> 3615298956
>    4363341525
>    4608966672

Новые ответы считает
Считало где-то по 10 минут

```
/*
 * To change this license header, choose License Headers in Project Properties.
 * To change this template file, choose Tools | Templates
 * and open the template in the editor.
 */
package time;

/**
 *
 * @author milan
 */
public class Time {

    /**
     * @param args the command line arguments
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println(i1023());
        System.out.println(i1024());
        System.out.println(i1025());



    }

    public static long i1023() {
        int mas1023_1[][] = new int[1023][1023];
        int mas1023_2[][] = new int[1023][1023];

        long ans[] = new long[10];
        long time1023 = 0;
        for (int k = 0; k < 10; k++) {
            long start;
            long finish;
            int[][] res = new int[1023][1023];

            start = System.nanoTime();
            for (int i = 0; i < 1023; i++) {
                for (int j = 0; j < 1023; j++) {
                    for (int l = 0; l < 1023; l++) {
                        res[i][j] += mas1023_1[i][l] * mas1023_2[l][j];
                    }
                }
            }
            finish = System.nanoTime();
            time1023 = finish - start;
            //System.out.println(time1023);
            ans[k] = time1023;
        }
        long sum = 0;
        for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
            sum += ans[i];
        }
        sum = sum / 10;
        return sum;
    }

    public static long i1024() {
        int mas1024_1[][] = new int[1024][1024];
        int mas1024_2[][] = new int[1024][1024];
        long ans[] = new long[10];
        long time1024 = 0;
        for (int k = 0; k < 10; k++) {
            long start;
            long finish;
            int[][] res = new int[1024][1024];

            start = System.nanoTime();
            for (int i = 0; i < 1024; i++) {
                for (int j = 0; j < 1024; j++) {
                    for (int l = 0; l < 1024; l++) {
                        res[i][j] += mas1024_1[i][l] * mas1024_2[l][j];
                    }
                }
            }
            finish = System.nanoTime();
            time1024 = finish - start;
            //System.out.println(time1024);
            ans[k] = time1024;
        }
        long sum = 0;
        for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
            sum += ans[i];
        }
        sum = sum / 10;
        return sum;
    }

    public static long i1025() {
        int mas1025_1[][] = new int[1025][1025];
        int mas1025_2[][] = new int[1025][1025];
        long ans[] = new long[10];
        long time1025 = 0;
        for (int k = 0; k < 10; k++) {
            long start;
            long finish;
            int[][] res = new int[1025][1025];
            start = System.nanoTime();
            for (int i = 0; i < 1025; i++) {
                for (int j = 0; j < 1025; j++) {
                    for (int l = 0; l < 1025; l++) {
                        res[i][j] += mas1025_1[i][l] * mas1025_2[l][j];
                    }
                }
            }
            finish = System.nanoTime();
            time1025 = finish - start;
            //System.out.println(time1025);
            ans[k] = time1025;
        }
        long sum = 0;
        for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
            sum += ans[i];
        }
        sum = sum / 10;
        return sum;
    }
}
```

Comment: Почему вы меряете время 2 внутренних циклов, а не всего умножения?

Comment: я считаю среднее арифметическое

Comment: Речь в вопросе про умножение матриц, мерять надо время выполнения трёх циклов, отвечающих за умножение

Comment: что на что умножать

Comment: Посмотрите на ответ @Harry, на Java код умножения почти такой же (C-подобный синтаксис)

Comment: Матрицу A размера 1023x1023 на матрицу B размера 1023x1023, матрицу A размера 1024х1024 на матрицу B размера 1024х1024, матрицу A размера 1025х1025 на матрицу B размера 1025x1025

Comment: Что-то в вашем примере нет умножения. При таком коде и у меня получается примерно то же самое :) - 1023: 5030
1024: 4689
1025: 4916

Comment: @Harry изменилл

Comment: Попробовал уже штук 6 онлайн сервисов, даже для одного умножения 1023х1023 получаю TL > 10, попробуйте всё же без вычисления среднего. А также оптимизирующий режим (если в Java такое есть)

Comment: О, всё, нашёл https://compiler.javatpoint.com/opr/online-java-compiler.jsp. 
Результаты: 
2594376933 
2623569130 
2519266493

Comment: и что с этим делать?)

Comment: @michael_best вставляете в класс Simple ваш код из класса Time и получаете результаты, соответствующие вопросу (1024х1024 медленнее 1025х1025)

Comment: а как вы вообще узнали, что 1024 медленнее?