# Почему алгоритм Штрассена резко замедляется после 2047?

Tags: c#, алгоритм

Я заметил матрицы размерностью от 1 до 2047 считаются за 6+- секунд

А начиная от 2048 начинают от 44 +- секунд. С чем может быть связан такой скачок во времени ?

при 2047 матрицы оперативка поднималась до 279 мб
при 2048 до 1042 мб

При этом оперативки хватает, тяжко просто считать ей становится

```
using System.Diagnostics;
using System.Text;
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        int m = 0, n = 0;
        while (true)
        {
            Stopwatch stopwatch = new Stopwatch();
            InputDate(ref m, "строк m");
            InputDate(ref n, "колонок n");

            int[][] matrix1 = GenerateMatrix(m, n);
            int[][] matrix2 = GenerateMatrix(m, n);
            int nn = GetNewDimension(ref m, ref n);

            int[][] aN = Addition2SquareMatrix(matrix1, nn, m, n);          
            int[][] bN = Addition2SquareMatrix(matrix2, nn, m, n);
           
            stopwatch.Start();
            int[][] temp = MultiStrassen(aN, bN, nn);

            stopwatch.Stop();

            //OutputMatrix(matrix1);
            //OutputMatrix(matrix2);
            //OutputMatrix(GetSubmatrix(temp, m, n));
            Console.WriteLine("\n" + stopwatch.Elapsed);
            Console.ReadKey();
        }
    }
    /// <summary>
    /// Ввод количество строк и столбцов
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="number">запись числа в переменную</param>
    /// <param name="txt">передаваемый текст</param>
    static void InputDate(ref int number, string txt)
    {
        do
        {
            Console.Write($"Введите число {txt}: ");
            number = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
        }
        while (number <= 0);
    }
    
    /// <summary>
    /// получаем новую степень матрицы
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="m">строка</param>
    /// <param name="n">столбец</param>
    /// <returns>возвращаем степень матрицы</returns>
    static int GetNewDimension(ref int m, ref int n) => 1 << (int)(Math.Log2(Math.Max(m, n))+1);
    
    /// <summary>
    /// Преобразуем матрицу к виду 2^n путём добавление дополнительных строк
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="a">передаваемый массив</param>
    /// <param name="nn">наша новая степень матрицы (размерность)</param>
    /// <param name="m">количество строк</param>
    /// <param name="n">количество столбцов</param>
    /// <returns>возвращаем обновленную матрицу</returns>
    static int[][] Addition2SquareMatrix(int[][] a, int nn, int m, int n)
    {       
        int[][] result = new int[nn][];
        for (int i = 0; i < nn; i++)
        {
            result[i] = new int[nn];
            if (i < m)
            {
                for (int j = 0; j < n; j++)
                {
                    result[i][j] = a[i][j];
                }
            }
        }           
        return result;            
    }
    /// <summary>
    /// Алгоритм Штрассена
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="a">1 матрица</param>
    /// <param name="b">2 матрица</param>
    /// <param name="n">размерность матрицы</param>
    /// <returns>возвращаем результат</returns>
    static int[][] MultiStrassen(int[][] a, int[][] b, int n)
    {
        if (n <= 64)
        {
            return Multiply(a, b);
        }

        n = n >> 1;

        int[][] a11 = new int[n][];
        int[][] a12 = new int[n][];
        int[][] a21 = new int[n][];
        int[][] a22 = new int[n][];

        int[][] b11 = new int[n][];
        int[][] b12 = new int[n][];
        int[][] b21 = new int[n][];
        int[][] b22 = new int[n][];

        for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
        {
            a11[i] = new int[n];
            a12[i] = new int[n];
            a21[i] = new int[n];
            a22[i] = new int[n];

            b11[i] = new int[n];
            b12[i] = new int[n];
            b21[i] = new int[n];
            b22[i] = new int[n];
        }

        SplitMatrix(a, a11, a12, a21, a22);
        SplitMatrix(b, b11, b12, b21, b22);

        int[][] p1 = MultiStrassen(Summation(a11, a22), Summation(b11, b22), n);
        int[][] p2 = MultiStrassen(Summation(a21, a22), b11, n);
        int[][] p3 = MultiStrassen(a11, Subtraction(b12, b22), n);
        int[][] p4 = MultiStrassen(a22, Subtraction(b21, b11), n);
        int[][] p5 = MultiStrassen(Summation(a11, a12), b22, n);
        int[][] p6 = MultiStrassen(Subtraction(a21, a11), Summation(b11, b12), n);
        int[][] p7 = MultiStrassen(Subtraction(a12, a22), Summation(b21, b22), n);

        int[][] c11 = Summation(Summation(p1, p4), Subtraction(p7, p5));
        int[][] c12 = Summation(p3, p5);
        int[][] c21 = Summation(p2, p4);
        int[][] c22 = Summation(Subtraction(p1, p2), Summation(p3, p6));
        return CollectMatrix(c11, c12, c21, c22);
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Разделение на матрицу на под матрицы
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="a">исходная матрица</param>
    /// <param name="a11">матрицы а11</param>
    /// <param name="a12">матрица а12</param>
    /// <param name="a21">матрица а21</param>
    /// <param name="a22">матрица а22</param>
    static void SplitMatrix(int[][] a, int[][] a11, int[][] a12, int[][] a21, int[][] a22)
    {
        int n = a.Length >> 1;

        for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
        {
            Array.Copy(a[i], 0, a11[i], 0, n);
            Array.Copy(a[i], n, a12[i], 0, n);
            Array.Copy(a[i + n], 0, a21[i], 0, n);
            Array.Copy(a[i + n], n, a22[i], 0, n);
        }
    }
    /// <summary>
    /// Объединение подматриц в одну матрицу
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="a11"></param>
    /// <param name="a12"></param>
    /// <param name="a21"></param>
    /// <param name="a22"></param>
    /// <returns>возвращаем объединённую матрицу</returns>
    static int[][] CollectMatrix(int[][] a11, int[][] a12, int[][] a21, int[][] a22)
    {
        int n = a11.Length;
        var b = (n << 1);

        int[][] a = new int[b][];
        for (int i = 0; i < b; i++)
        {
            a[i] = new int[b];
        }

        for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
        {
            Array.Copy(a11[i], 0, a[i], 0, n);
            Array.Copy(a12[i], 0, a[i], n, n);
            Array.Copy(a21[i], 0, a[i + n], 0, n);
            Array.Copy(a22[i], 0, a[i + n], n, n);
        }

        return a;
    }
    /// <summary>
    /// Разность между матрицами
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="a">матрица 1</param>
    /// <param name="b">матрица 2</param>
    /// <returns>результат разности матриц</returns>
    static int[][] Subtraction(int[][] a, int[][] b)
    {
        int n = a.Length;
        int m = a[0].Length;
        int[][] c = new int[n][];

        for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
        {
            c[i] = new int[m];
            for (int j = 0; j < m; j++)
            {
                c[i][j] = a[i][j] - b[i][j];
            }
        }
        return c;
    }
    /// <summary>
    /// Умножение матриц
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="a"></param>
    /// <param name="b"></param>
    /// <returns>результат умножения </returns>
    static int[][] Multiply(int[][] a, int[][] b)
    {
        int rowsA = a.Length;
        int columnsB = b[0].Length;
        int columnsA_rowsB = a[0].Length;

        int[][] c = new int[rowsA][];
        for (int i = 0; i < rowsA; i++)
        {
            c[i] = new int[columnsB];
            for (int j = 0; j < columnsB; j++)
            {
                int sum = 0;
                for (int k = 0; k < columnsA_rowsB; k++)
                {
                    sum += a[i][k] * b[k][j];
                }
                c[i][j] = sum;
            }
        }
        return c;
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Суммирование матриц
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="a"></param>
    /// <param name="b"></param>
    /// <returns></returns>
    static int[][] Summation(int[][] a, int[][] b)
    {
        int n = a.Length;
        int m = a[0].Length;
        int[][] c = new int[n][];
        for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
        {
            c[i] = new int[m];
        }

        for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
        {
            for (int j = 0; j < m; j++)
            {
                c[i][j] = a[i][j] + b[i][j];
            }
        }

        return c;
    }
    /// <summary>
    /// Убирает лишние строки матриц
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="a"></param>
    /// <param name="n"></param>
    /// <param name="m"></param>
    /// <returns>возвращаем матрицу</returns>
    static int[][] GetSubmatrix(int[][] a, int n, int m)
    {        
        int[][] result = new int[n][];
        for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
        {
            result[i] = new int[m];
            Array.Copy(a[i], 0, result[i], 0, m);
        }
        return result;       
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Генерация произвольного размера матрицы
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="m">количество строк</param>
    /// <param name="n">количество столбцов</param>
    /// <returns>возврощаем матрицу</returns>
    static int[][] GenerateMatrix(int m, int n)
    {
        Random rand = new Random();
        int[][] matrix = new int[m][];

        for (int i = 0; i < m; i++)
        {
            matrix[i] = new int[n];
            for (int j = 0; j < n; j++)
            {
                matrix[i][j] = rand.Next(1, 100);
            }
        }
        return matrix;
    }
    /// <summary>
    /// Вывод на экран матриц
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="matrix"></param>
    static void OutputMatrix(int[][] matrix)
    {
        var sb = new StringBuilder();
        foreach (int[] row in matrix)
        {
            foreach (int element in row)
            {
                sb.Append(element);
                sb.Append(' ');
            }
            sb.Length--;
            sb.AppendLine();
        }
        Console.WriteLine($"\n" + sb);
    }
}
```

Comment: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/926660/195342

Comment: @Harry, ваш пример уводит в сторону. Там компилятор учитывал фиксированные размеры массивов. Здесь такого нет.

Comment: `Он вам покажет что число прохамов` - Лозунг "будьте проактивными" - это, видимо, для них...

Comment: @ESkri, спасибо что обратили моё внимание. Я перечитал задачу и понял что кэш не при чем. Стёр свои комментарии.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Функция `GetNewDimension(m, n)` считает размер до которого надо растянуть матрицы, чтобы с ними мог работать алгоритм Штрассена. Это должна быть степень двойки:

> ```
> n (= m)   GetNewDimension(m, n)
>  2047            2048
>  2048            4096                      Зачем?
>  2049            4096
> ```

Зачем *2048* увеличивается до *4096*? *2048* уже степень двойки. Можно было оставить без изменений:

```
static int GetNewDimension2(ref int m, ref int n) =>
    1 << (int)Math.Ceiling(Math.Log2(Math.Max(m, n)));
```

Теперь ступенька на *2048* пропала. Но она перебралась на *2049*. Это нормально, алгоритм Штрассена переключается на следующую степень двойки и замедляется примерно в семь раз.

Нам не нужно чтобы размер матрицы был степенью двойки. Достаточно чтобы размер матрицы делился пополам до тех пор пока он не станет *≤ 64*. Матрицы маленьких размеров умножаются обычным алгоритмом умножения, который работает с любыми размерами матриц.

Если *2049* увеличить до *2112*, то алгоритм Штрассена поделит размер пополам шесть раз и получит матрицу размера *33* (*= 2112 / 2<sup>6</sup>*), которую передаст обычному умножению.

Вот новая функция:

```
static int GetNewDimension(ref int m, ref int n)
{
    int b = 64;
    int k = Math.Max(n, m);
    int f = 1 << (int)Math.Ceiling(Math.Log2((k + b - 1) / b));
    return f * ((k + f - 1) / f);
}
```

Времена работы на моей машине. Хотя ступеньки остались, они стали гораздо ниже:

> ```
> n (= m)   GetNewDimension(m, n)     Время работы
>  2047            2048                  14.18
>  2048            2048                  14.19
>  2049            2112                  17.48
>  2050            2112                  17.85
>  ...
>  2111            2112                  17.80
>  2112            2112                  17.46
>  2113            2176                  18.86
>  2114            2176                  18.99
>  ...
>  2175            2176                  18.74
>  2176            2176                  18.80
>  2177            2240                  20.04
>  2178            2240                  20.03
> ```

**P.S.** От ступенек можно избавиться полностью, но потребуется много переделок в основной процедуре, а выигрыш в сравнении с текущим вариантом составит не более десяти процентов. А так дёшево и сердито.

Comment: Класс! Я реально этот нюанс проморгал.